# Установка Credentials plugin для Jenkins

Tags: плагин, jenkins

Пытаюсь разбираться с Дженкинсом. Проблема, что при установке плагинов он постоянно валится с ошибкой. Методом перебора и логов проблема обозначилась с плагином Credentials, который хочет и maven и git. Ошибка из лога томката ниже. Пробовал разные версии. Есть ощущение, что нужно что-то где-то настроить в конфигах или доступах.
В какую хоть сторону копать? Спасибо!
Windows 10, Tomcat 10, Java 21, Jenkins 2.426.1 
часть из лога

```
21-Dec-2023 11:34:03.830 WARNING [pool-7-thread-6] hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$SezpozModule.configure Failed to load com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.GlobalCredentialsConfiguration
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$SezpozModule.resolve(ExtensionFinder.java:531)
        at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$SezpozModule.resolve(ExtensionFinder.java:488)
        at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$SezpozModule.configure(ExtensionFinder.java:573)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:64)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:426)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:113)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:160)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
        at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder.<init>(ExtensionFinder.java:282)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at net.java.sezpoz.IndexItem.instance(IndexItem.java:181)
        at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz._find(ExtensionFinder.java:748)
        at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz.find(ExtensionFinder.java:734)
        at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:344)
        at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:384)
        at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:320)
        at hudson.ExtensionList.getComponents(ExtensionList.java:184)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$6.onInitMilestoneAttained(Jenkins.java:1202)
        at jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1.onAttained(InitReactorRunner.java:88)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.lambda$onAttained$3(ReactorListener.java:108)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.run(ReactorListener.java:116)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.onAttained(ReactorListener.java:108)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$1.run(Reactor.java:182)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:120)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at jenkins.util.URLClassLoader2.findClass(URLClassLoader2.java:35)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 37 more
21-Dec-2023 11:34:03.941 WARNING [pool-7-thread-6] hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$SezpozModule.configure Failed to load hudson.tasks.JavadocArchiver$DescriptorImpl
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$SezpozModule.resolve(ExtensionFinder.java:531)
        at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$SezpozModule.resolve(ExtensionFinder.java:488)
```